# Lambda function can not access appsync

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have a lambda function create by amplify to get a list of donors from appsync but it will get UnauthorizedException every time I try to request. Here is my lambda function:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const gql = require('graphql-tag');
const graphql = require('graphql');
const { print } = graphql;

const listDonors = gql`
    query listDonors {
        listDonors {
            items {
                id
                firstName
                lastName
            }
        }
    }
`

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log("--------------------------------->");
    try {
        const graphqlData = await axios({
            url: process.env.API_DOCBACKEND_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT,
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'x-api-key': process.env.API_DOCBACKEND_GRAPHQLAPIIDOUTPUT
            },
            data: {
                query: print(listDonors),
            }
        });
        const body = {
            graphqlData: graphqlData.data.data.listTodos
        }
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error posting to appsync: ', err);
    }
}
```

Here is my IAM role:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "appsync:Create*",
            "appsync:StartSchemaCreation",
            "appsync:GraphQL",
            "appsync:Get*",
            "appsync:List*",
            "appsync:Update*",
            "appsync:Delete*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:appsync:us-east-1:862148551361:apis/2i62fn5z4vhtxbik3jcm33tc6e/types/Query/*",
            "arn:aws:appsync:us-east-1:862148551361:apis/2i62fn5z4vhtxbik3jcm33tc6e/types/Mutation/*",
            "arn:aws:appsync:us-east-1:862148551361:apis/2i62fn5z4vhtxbik3jcm33tc6e/types/Subscription/*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
]
```

}

I follow the aws amplify document but it does not help me anything at all.

Comment: post your error message

Comment: Here is my error message:
Error: Request failed with status code 401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awsappsync.html#awsappsync-field) seems to indicate that you should pass a field or a graphqlapi to the `GraphQL` permission.

- field should read `arn:${Partition}:appsync:${Region}:${Account}:apis/${GraphQLAPIId}/types/${TypeName}/fields/${FieldName}`
- graphqlapi should read `arn:${Partition}:appsync:${Region}:${Account}:apis/${GraphQLAPIId}`

It seems to me like `arn:aws:appsync:us-east-1:xxx:apis/xxx/types/Query/*` does not quite match the rule.

Maybe you should replace it with `arn:aws:appsync:us-east-1:xxx:apis/xxx"` to use the `graphqlapi` format

Or use the field format: `arn:aws:appsync:us-east-1:xxx:apis/xxx/types/Query/fields/*` (and do the same for other types, obviously) ?